# PHP5 scripts are not executing in apache2 (Linux Mint)

Tags: php, linux, apache, apache2, php-5.3

I've never tired this on another machine since I'm already sure it has to deal with my configuration but no idea how I'd approach it. Basically I have one file called info.php which contains:

```
<?php
    echo sqlite_libversion();
    echo "<br>";
    echo phpinfo();
    echo "test";
?>
```

Nothing gets outputed on the browser. I've followed this tutorial as well: [Installing Lamp](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486)

Comment: Have you checked the error log?  What does it say?

Comment: In /etc/apache2/ there isn't an Error.log to be found :/

Answer (score 0):

Mayabe your firewall is on?

please put the iptables(Redhat/debian) or firewalld(fedora) to stop

```
#service iptables stop
```

and check it again

You should install sqlite package.

On Redhat like sysem

```
#yum install php5-sqlite
```

On Debian/ubunutu

```
#apt-get install php5-sqlite
```